# Manually set color legend for Plotly line plot

Tags: python, plotly, visualization

I would like to fix colors for my legend in a plotly line graph. Basically, I have a dataframe `df` in which there is a column `Sex`. I already know that my dataframe will hold only 3 possible values in that column.

So I would like to fix colors ie. Green for `Male`, Blue for `Female` and Yellow for `Other`. This should also hold true when there are no occurrences in the `df` for one category i.e. `Male`.

Currently, my code auto-defaults colors. For ex: If `df` contains all categories, it sets Blue for Male, Yellow for Female, Green for Other. But when, `df` only holds values containing Male and Female, the color preferences change, thereby losing consistency.

Code is as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(...)

lineplot = px.line(
        df, 
        x="Date", 
        y='Ct', 
        color='Sex',
        title=f"Lineplot to keep track of people across time"
    )
lineplot.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the colours individually using `color_discrete_map` argument. [Ref](https://community.plotly.com/t/plotly-express-line-chart-color/27333/5) and still keep the specific color which we set manually:

```py
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    Date=[1,2,3],
    Male   = [1,2,3],
    Female = [2,3,1],
    Others = [7,5,2]
))


fig = px.line(df, x="Date", y=["Male",
                              # "Female", comment this type for testing color
                               "Others"],
             color_discrete_map={
                 "Male": "#456987",
                 "Female": "#147852",
                 "Others": "#00D",
                 
             })

fig.show()
```

---

output:

[image: img]